# Inheriting IContainerAcessor on global.asax causes Parser Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have started to work on a `ASP.NET MVC` Unity web project that is building and running successfully for my peers, however when I attempt to run the project I get the following `Parser Error` that references line 1 of my `Global.asax` file:

> "Parser Error Message: Signature of the body and declaration in a
>   method implementation do not match."
>
> This error can be avoided by removing the reference to
>   `IContainerAccessor` and the inherited container property from
>   Global.asax.cs.

When I try to debug the problem by putting a breakpoint at the beginning of `Application_Start`, the build will still work but I receive the error page without hitting the breakpoint.

This problem persists even after getting exactly what is working for others via source control. I am not sure what else I can try, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you edit the app.config file while the project is running, the breakpoint will be hit.

Comment: Editing the web.config while the project is running is blocked by Visual Studio and editing it externally does not trigger the breakpoint.

Comment: The app config in th \bin folder..

Comment: That doesn't trigger the breakpoint either.

Comment: That's odd, editing the web.config should force the app to restart.

Comment: Can you post the code of your Global.asax?

Comment: Sure, it is the same as what I posted below in the error message: <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="x.Global" Language="C#" %>

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons for that error message:

**1 Your local web server is running different code than what you're
    actually working on**:
 to fix that try this:

- stop debugging.
- stop your local web server
- clean and rebuild
- You might need to re-create the Virtual Directory.

**2 Your local project is pointing to a a dll library version that is different than the one in the source control**

Comment: I don't think the problem is that the server is running different code than what I am working on since I can trigger this error by inheriting the IContainerAccessor and clear the error by removing that reference. The code seems to be updating what is on the server each time I change the file. I don't think the local project is pointing to the wrong library either because I get the same error after completely removing the project from my local machine and getting exactly what is in source control.

Comment: Did you post the entire error message regarding the parse error? did you ignore to post the rest of the error?

Comment: That is the entire error. Header of Parser Error, description text of "Signature of body..." etc and a reference to the single line of my Global.asax file. Here is the entirety of the error page with the namespace altered:

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match.  Type: 'x.Global'.  Assembly: 'x, Version=x.x.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="x.Global" Language="C#" %>
Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

Comment: I think it's your IIS . what version of ASP.NET version running on your IIS and which version is your app?

Comment: Another thing you can try : delete the content of your BIN folder , compile your solution and run it.share the result

Comment: I tried deleting /bin and cleaning / rebuilding without any luck. I am using IIS express for VS 2013 at ASP.NET 4.5. I got the same error when using Local IIS as well.

Comment: Then it's your Unity container . focus on that , the injection implementation is interfering somehow

Comment: If it were the Unity container I would expect the other people grabbing the same thing from source control to have the same problem but it works for them. Unfortunately I am new to Unity so I don't know exactly how I would debug it from that side of things either. Thanks for all your suggestions so far!